# Create a White List of USB Mass Storage devices permited in a GPO Active Directory with Serial Numbers

Tags: usb, group-policy

I have a Web form where I put the serial numbers of all USB flash drives that are permitted in my Network. Dynamically, my Ubuntu hosts consult, by a script, this list and block or permit the USB flash drives to be mounted. In Linux platform I used the UDEV services to trigger this script.

I know that in Microsoft platform there are the policies and in registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions\AllowInstanceIDs,
it could be typed something like USB\COMPOSITE\7891011121314151617181920.

So, consider the steps:

1 - I already have the serial numbers, but in 1234567890 format in a web page;

2 - I know that it is possible to update a list with a command like >iwr http://my_form_serial_numbers.html -OutFile C:\Users%USER%\AppData\Local\serial.txt;

**The questions are**:

How to allow only the listed serial numbers mentioned above to mount?

How to update the serial list in Active Directory dynamically?

Comment: Anderson, who is updating the allowable USB dev ids in the Linux solution? The list is not dynamic is it or does it take human interaction to add to it or to remove from it. I assume you are not looking for "dynamic" with this respect, correct? You just want to be able to tell the Windows OS to allow only the USB UUIDs or whatever you have in your list to be the ONLY allowable devices to mount and such? If there's a policy, there is a way to script it to apply to add to applicable registry keys, etc. GPO could run at startup and you could potentially even trigger on USB plugin event too. Ideas

Comment: This subject is treated in depth in this [Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731387(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and especially in the section of [Steps for allowing users to install only authorized devices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731387(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#steps-for-allowing-users-to-install-only-authorized-devices). This is a rather old document, but please check if it still applies to your setup.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle, many question... so by steps: 1 - Yes, I update the new serialNumbers in a web form. It generate a web page and update a list of serialNumbers like: >iwr http://my_form_serial_numbers.html -OutFile C:\Users%USER%\AppData\Local\serial.txt;    2-  Yes, but sometimes I will to insert or delete the new ones SerialNumbers stick memories in a webform. And the Policy list, or whatever, need to be update too. 3 - I want to allow the ONLY listed devices to mount.

Comment: @AndersonFidelis Here's a link that gives the correlated registry path for this feature (https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.DeviceInstallation::DeviceInstall_IDs_Allow). Are you able to get this setup on a test machine with 2 USB drives, only allow 1 via the registry settings, and then test to see if this prevents the 1 you did not allow from installing and being mounted. You have to defined this one too though: https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.DeviceInstallation::DeviceInstall_Unspecified_Deny

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle, I already know these techinique, but my list is 1234567890 format. In this case I need to type USB\COMPOSITE\1234567890, or something like this. I need to consult the list, independent if will be in dynamic or static mode. And it could to impact in linux aplication, already implemented. WHATEVER, I WILL TO TEST BEFORE TO CLOSE A IDEA. PLEASE, STILL HELPS ME

Comment: Okay, great. You know for certain that using those policies does work for your needs to do the blocking, but you want to prevent having to add `1234567890`, etc. to the policy explicitly. I'm curious to see what the correlated registry exported looks like for the key that contains the allow list. You can have a PowerShell script create the `-outfile` via `Invoke-WebRequest` and figure out the trivial logic to parse to get an array of values. It will then inject any missing from the correlated registry key to it. This can be done at computer restart easily. Trigger it to run as USB connect too.

Comment: If you can [edit] your question and add an example of the exported `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions` along with all values within and such, I can help get a script built that can check it and append the values in the website HTML to `USB\COMPOSITE\1234567890` format for your needs. I can help you get this setup as a startup script too via GPO to run and update the allowed listed per reboot of each device. Triggering with a specific event should be possible too but would like you to find applicable event ID that will also trigger the script to run.

Comment: Have you looked at [Steps for allowing users to install only authorized devices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731387(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#steps-for-allowing-users-to-install-only-authorized-devices)?

Comment: @harrymc, I already have read about, but like I have said above, I need to consult a list, from my website

Comment: @AndersonFidelis Yes, getting the list from your website and transforming the list into another list/array appending the `USB\COMPOSITE\<list item value>` is possible. You then take that list and inject that into the correlated registry value and set the registry values for the allowed device ids. This is all possible and is just a trivial matter and I can get you logic in a script to do this. If you can do a little footwork and [edit] your question with that exported registry with even just two or three USB device IDs for examples for me so I know what I'm working with there, I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use the Task Scheduler
to schedule a task that will at a determined time
(for example on boot or on login) either:

- Download and execute a `.reg` file,
- Download and execute a script containing
  [REG commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg).

To allow installation of devices that match any of these device IDs,
use the following registry keys:

Key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions`
Value Name: `AllowDeviceIDs`
Type: `REG_DWORD`
Value Data: `0` - Disable, `1` – Enable

Key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions\AllowDeviceIDs`
Value Name: `1` (ascending series, followed by `2`, `3` etc.)
Type: `REG_SZ`
Value Data: "Hardware ID of the Device"

Note that the `AllowDeviceIDs` policy is described by Microsoft as:

> This policy setting allows you to specify a list of Plug and Play
> hardware IDs and compatible IDs for devices that Windows is allowed to
> install. Use this policy setting only when the "Prevent installation
> of devices not described by other policy settings" policy setting is
> enabled.
>
> Other policy settings that prevent device installation take precedence
> over this one.
>
> If you enable this policy setting, Windows is allowed to install or
> update any device whose Plug and Play hardware ID or compatible ID
> appears in the list you create, unless another policy setting
> specifically prevents that installation (for example, the "Prevent
> installation of devices that match any of these device IDs" policy
> setting, the "Prevent installation of devices for these device
> classes" policy setting, or the "Prevent installation of removable
> devices" policy setting).
>
> If you enable this policy setting on a remote desktop server, the
> policy setting affects redirection of the specified devices from a
> remote desktop client to the remote desktop server.
>
> If you disable or do not configure this policy setting, and no other
> policy setting describes the device, the "Prevent installation of
> devices not described by other policy settings" policy setting
> determines whether the device can be installed.

Comment: ,, I tested, and I have some constations: 1 - the memory stick only can be mount if I already had installed before to apply the policy; 2 - if I restart the machine, with the pendrive plugged it mount independent of the allowed serial Numbers.

Comment: You mean that a device that is plugged-in before the computer was rebooted is still mounted and usable? If so, is the the policy "Prevent installation of devices not described by other policy settings" enabled?

Comment: It still not coming in a easy way. I dont know why, but the computers policies don't work well in my active directory :(.